# Making two divs stick to the top of page after scrolled past

Tags: html, css-position

I've been trying to make two divs stick to the top of the page after the user scrolled past these divs. Both divs are positioned at the same hight. This is what I have been using from other stackoverflow answers:

Html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top)
    $('#blockleft').addClass('sticky')
  else
    $('#blockleft').removeClass('sticky');
  }
 $(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div class="container">
<div id="blockleft"></div>
<div id="blockright"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Css:

```
body  {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
}
#header {
 height:200px;
 background-color:#666;
}
#blockleft {
 width:100px;
 height:500px;
 margin-top:10px;
 background-color:#090;
 float:left;
}
#blockright {
 width:100px;
 height:500px;
 margin-top:10px;
 background-color:#0F3;
 float:right;
}
#content {
 width:500px;
 height:2000px;
 background-color:#0CF;
 margin:auto;
}
.container {
 width:800px;
 margin:auto;
}
.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
}
```

The script is working fine on one div, but when using the script twice it automatically moves the right div to the left and this one is not sticking to the top of the page.

I was hoping someone could help me out with this one.

**Edit: Recreated the problem in a new document**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `div`s lose `float` property when we make it `position:fixed`, they both overlap with each other. In order to make them in their position, we need to apply `right` distance for the right `div`. To fix this, replace your script code as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function sticky_relocate() {
  var containerWidth = $(".container").outerWidth(true);
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top)
  {
    $('#blockleft').addClass('sticky');
    $('#blockright').addClass('sticky');
    $('#blockright').css("right", (containerWidth-800)/2 + "px");
    }
  else
  {
    $('#blockleft').removeClass('sticky');
    $('#blockright').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  }
 $(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
  });
</script>
```

The code `$('#blockright').css("right", (containerWidth-800)/2 + "px");` calculates the right distance value for the right `div` and adds css property `right:XXXpx` to that `div` while scrolling. The code `var containerWidth = $(".container").outerWidth(true);` fetches the width of the container `div` with its `margin` value (since `margin` is made `auto`, we need definite number for calculation)

Comment: I recreated the problem in a new file, maybe this one is easier to understand. Please check the original post.

Comment: @LittleLumber: please mark this as answer, if this helps you to resolve your issue.